# c# ef core RemoveRange contraint violation

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

Hi I have a complex db with many tables and relations
what we want to do is to copy all tables from a database to another but only taking rows starting from one table (salesorder) and going down following relations.
So I avoided the .Include, and use IQueryable queries (one for each table)
there is no problem with the insert

the problem is when I want to delete all rows from all tables I got a constraint violation
I use .RemoveRange(tableRowsqueryable)

I have already tried to disable all FK check, but when I do reenable I get the same error

the error

> SqlException: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE
> constraint "FK_InvParty_Stop_InvParty". The conflict occurred in
> database "UDM", table "dbo.InvParty_Stop", column 'InvPartyID'.

the InvPartyID column is also in the PK of InvParty_Stop table

I have tried debugging to check if there is something missing, but I don't see nothing wrong!
The other solution is to use a stored procedure to do this job

Comment: You have to delete the rows of the table associated first or dissociate

Comment: is there a way to see what generate this conflict? i mean the rows/id or something more specific?

Comment: search the row in the associated table using the constraints from the table that you are trying to delete, the column `FK_InvParty_Stop_InvParty` looks like `InvPartyID` from InvParty_Stop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an item with a foreign key relation is deleted or updated you need to specify what you need to do with related records. These settings are performed at the DB level. You can check the syntax reference [on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-column-constraint-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15).
You have these options:

> [ ON DELETE { NO ACTION | CASCADE | SET NULL | SET DEFAULT } ]

- NO ACTION - The default behavior when you have an error
- CASCADE - Delete related records. When all related records are deleted implicitly.
- SET NULL and SET DEFAULT - Update Reference values with NULL or a default value

You can check the detailed description in the following [help article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/primary-and-foreign-key-constraints?view=sql-server-ver15) and choose that best approach in your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, if you have one table associated to another. That can happen if you try to delete that one row associated.

Example:

```
| Table Person  | Table Car   |
| ------------  | ----------- |
| ID            | ID          |
| Name          | PersonFK_ID |
```

As you can see above, the table Person is associated to the table car. Let' see some data.

```
| Table Person      |
|  ---------------  |
| ID    |  Name     |
| 1     | Mark      |
| 2     | Caio      |
| 3     | David     |
|  ---------------  |
| Table Car         |
| ID  | PersonFK_ID |
| 10  | 2           |
| 11  | 1           |
```

Now if you try to delete the person with id 1, this will inform a conflict with the data from car with ID `11` PersonFK_ID `1`. Now if you try delete any row from Table car, there's no conflict, because the table car is not associated with others tables. Then, to delete the person with id `1`, first delete the car with id `11`.

You can deal in two simple ways with this problem:

1 - deleting the data associated;

2 - transforming the foreign column in a simple column.

OBS: `the column FK_InvParty_Stop_InvParty looks like InvPartyID from InvParty_Stop`

You can search other way if you want to.